# How to get exact time of Session Out before logout to store in Database in .NET

Tags: asp.net

To Store Last login, I want to Store the session timeout value before logout of Particular User.

Comment: Why not just store the current time?

Comment: With what exactly do you have a problem? Please specify some details about what you tried.

Comment: why don't you implement this thing in the logout action method?

Comment: Juz want to store the last logout time. Bt if a user session is out before logging out, den how can i store the particular session out time.